# ROS Answers SE migration: ps3joy on OSX

Tags: macos, ps3joy, macos-mountain-lion, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see the package for Linux to use a [PS3 Dual Shock joystick](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ps3joy), but is there a similar package for OSX? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12803/ps3joy-on-osx/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have finally found a way to use my PS3 controller with ROS that doesn't involve my having to learn Python. I wrote a simple package call [osx_joystick](https://github.com/walchko/osx_joystick) that will publish either sensor_msgs::Joy or geometry_msgs::Twist based on the analog sticks or button values.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There does not seem to be an option for that on Mac just yet.

I use rososc and my iPhone for driving stuff or simulations with my mac.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rososc

http://www.ros.org/wiki/teleop_handler

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-02-29**:
Yes, I have played with that on my iPad. It was cool, but I still think the joystick is better. Since I have 4 of the ps3 joysticks, I would love to get one of them working.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-03-04**:
Strange ... I just went to ros.org and tried to [search](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?q=rososc) for the rososc code and it said: Didn't find anything relating to 'rososc'. Going straight to your link above works fine.